# When i open android studio project it is showing different characters in files

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

i am trying to open the project in android studio when i open the project it is showing some different characters in editor

Comment: Make sure that the distributionUrl inside the gradle wrapper properties file is correct.

Comment: @SMVaidhyanathan the same characters are shown in the gradle wrapper properties file how to make changes in the gradle wrapper properties file